# How to rewrite nginx base country

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

If user come from French:

```
www.example.com -> www.example.com/fr
www.example.com/blog -> www.example.com/fr/blog
www.example.com/contact -> www.example.com/fr/contact
```

...
Same with country VietNam.
I have write some code on file example.conf but it not working:

```
server_name www.example.com;
root /srv/www/example.com;
if ($country ~* "(vi|fr)") {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$country$1 permanent;
  break;
}
```

Anyone can help me ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx_http_geoip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) or handle [Accept Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657614/how-to-rewrite-location-in-nginx-depending-on-the-client-browsers-language) header.