# NGINX rewrite root url with language suffix

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add a simple rule to my NGINX configuration whereby the root url `www.example.com` is always rewritten with a language suffix `www.example.com/en/`. I have tried this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^$ www.example.com/en/ permanent;
    }

    ...
}
```

But no luck. Where am I going wrong? Also, is it possible to have a condition where NGINX checks if there is an`/en/` suffix and if not, adds one?

**EDIT**

So I was only one character away from what I wanted initially:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        # needed the / in between the anchor tags
        rewrite ^/$ www.example.com/en/ permanent;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You could use the [accept language module](http://Accept%20language%20module%20is%20your%20friend). Also, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657614/how-to-rewrite-location-in-nginx-depending-on-the-client-browsers-language) looks very similar to yours

Comment: I don't think I need to use the language module. My priority is just rewriting the root url `/` to `/en/`. For the time being I'm happy that any url without the suffix returns a 404.

Comment: In the answer that I linked the are examples on how to do exactly that.

Comment: The answer to the first part of my question was very simple - just needed the `/` inbetween the `^` and  `$` anchors.

Comment: Does `location / { ... }` not indicate that?

Comment: Also, repeating the server value is not a good practice, you could just use $server_name variable. that way will be reusable on other locations if needed or better yet avoid using it at all: `rewrite (.*) $uri/en;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two normal ways to deal with redirects:

### Using a rewrite rule

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/$ /en/ permanent;    
    ...
}
```

Note that [rewrite rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) do not need to be absolute urls, but if they *are* to be absolute urls they need to include the protocol `rewrite /x https://example.com/y;`.

There is no need to put rewrite rules like this in a location block.

### Using a location block + return 30x

Using a location block requires using an exact match for the url:

```
server {
    ...
    location = / {
        return 301 /en/;
    }
    ...
}
```

The use of `=` means the rule will *only* match requests for the root of the domain, otherwise the [rules of location block precedence](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) mean that the location block would be the default for all requests. [Return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) is used to issue a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: For simplicity, if you are redirecting to the same scheme and host, you can omit both and just do `return 301 /en/;`