# Can not use 301 redirect in NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a web site which is translated to 18 languages. Some languages are the same (Brazilian is Portuguese). So I want to redirect from *br* to *pt* to avoid odd content, from `/some_domain/br/...` -> `/some_domain/pt/...`

I can write single redirect from one domain to another. Something like this:

```
location = /user/unique {
       return 301 http://www.usgreencardoffice.com/blog/the-american-dream;
    }
```

I want to achieve the following:
`domain.com/br/something` -> `domain.com/pt/something`

But for the languages redirection, I have no idea. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657614/how-to-rewrite-location-in-nginx-depending-on-the-client-browsers-language) post might help solve your problems

Comment: This post is about another problem, which can be solved by right routing directly from the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language code is at the beginning of the URI, a prefix location will be an efficient solution:

```
location ^~ /br/ {
    rewrite ^/br(.*)$ /pt$1 permanent;
}
```

The `^~` modifier makes this prefix location take precedence over regex locations at the same level. If you change `permanent` to `last`, the rewrite becomes internal and thus invisible to the user.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Great! The problem is solved! Thanks you for details.