# Redirect website visitor to bowser language in Nginx (url rewrite)

Tags: php, nginx

Greetings to everyone!

I'm struggling to Redirect website visitor to bowser language in Nginx to their browser language, I'm trying to do this on Nginx using url rewrite rules, and so far nothing.

I have already googled and tried different options but I'm not getting anywhere.

My website has 4 or 5 languages but one must be set by default, it's not possible to disable this, so my purpose is to redirect the website default language to visitors browser default language.

Example:

https://mywebsite.com/ (default url will show default lang) but if the website is visited by english visitor that chooses english lang on website, the main url will change like to

1. English visitor https://mywebsite.com/?language=english
2. Spanish visitor https://mywebsite.com/?language=spanish
3. French visitor  https://mywebsite.com/?language=french

So what code do you guys recommend for Nginx rewrite rules? I'm trying to avoid messing with index.php, but in last case it's possible.

I would be much appreciated if you guys could help, I'm not expert in Nginx rules nor php.

Thanks

Comment: Look into the [map syntax](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) and check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/3657614/231316

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite location in nginx depending on the client-browser's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657614/how-to-rewrite-location-in-nginx-depending-on-the-client-browsers-language)